# Efficient way to apply pandas operation many times to identically indexed objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am performing a fixed point iteration which requires multiple evaluations of function `f` i.e.

```
x <- f(x)
```

In programming terms, `x` is a Pandas series indexed by a multiindex. The function `f` is not able to work elementwise on `x`. It first merges it with a parameter dataframe, applies some elementwise operations and then groups and sums, to output an object with the exact same index as `x`.

My question concerns the first and third index modifying operations. They are essentially always making the same modification to the index and I was wondering if there was a way to store them to increase the efficiency of applying `f` many times?

Consider the following example

```
x = pd.DataFrame(
        [
          [20160404, 'John', 2],
          [20160404, 'Mark', 1],
          [20160405, 'John', 5],
          [20160405, 'Mark', 1],
          [20160406, 'John', 6],
          [20160406, 'Mark', 2],
        ], 
        columns=['DATE', 'NAME', 'VALUE'] 
    ).set_index(['DATE', 'NAME'])

z = pd.DataFrame(
        [
          [20160404, 'John', 0, 0.2],
          [20160404, 'John', 0, 0.2],
          [20160404, 'John', 1, 0.3],
          [20160404, 'John', 1, 0.3],
          [20160404, 'Mark', 1, 0.7],
          [20160405, 'John', 1, 0.2],
          [20160405, 'Mark', 0, 0.0],
          [20160406, 'John', 1, 0.9],
          [20160406, 'Mark', 1, 0.3]
        ], 
        columns=['DATE', 'NAME', 'SITU', 'VALUE'] 
    ).set_index(['DATE', 'NAME', 'SITU'])

def f(x):
    # 1) Merge x onto z
    df = pd.merge(z.reset_index(), x.reset_index(),
                  on=['DATE', 'NAME'], suffixes=['_z', '_x'])     

    # 2) Perform elementwise operation
    df['VALUE'] = df['VALUE_z']*df['VALUE_x']

    # 3) Group and operate (sum) over the 'SITU' column
    df = df.groupby(['DATE', 'NAME'])['VALUE'].sum()

    return df

for i in range(10):
    x = f(x)
```

The point here is the 1st and 3rd operations essentially always do the same thing (to the index) the only thing that changes is the `VALUE_x` column, varying for `x` on each iteration.

We can see this more clearly in the following code which has removed the Pandas index and just uses Numpy arrays.

```
x = np.array([2, 1, 5, 1, 6, 2])
z = np.array([0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.2, 0.0, 0.9, 0.3])

merge_idx = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
group_idx = np.array([
                       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
                     ])

def f(x):
    return group_idx @ (x[merge_idx]*z)
```

Hence knowing `group_idx` and `merge_idx` (which are used in the 1st and 3rd step) allows us to quickly perform our function operation. These could have been pre-calculated and if there is a way to do that using Pandas it would solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is not exactly what you're looking for, but it should be more efficient.  Simply get rid of `SITU`, squeeze both to actual Series, and take advantage of the fact that Pandas operations are naturally index-aligned.

```
from itertools import repeat

def f(x_, z_, rpt=10):
    for _ in repeat(None, rpt):
        x_ = z_ * x_
        x_ = x_.groupby(level=(0, 1)).sum()
    return x_

z_ = z.reset_index(level=-1, drop=True).squeeze()
x_ = x.squeeze()

new = f(x_, z_)
```

This gets rid of:

- two `reset_index()` calls in each loop
- an explicit `merge()` in each loop
- needing to index columns i.e. `['VALUE']`

If you do want to stick with your current route, I think `.get_indexer_for()` might be what you're looking for:

```
>>> x_.index.get_indexer_for(z_.index)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

And to get to `group_idx`, again from your question:

```
>>> group_idx = np.zeros((len(np.unique(merge_idx)), len(merge_idx)))
>>> group_idx[merge_idx, np.arange(len(merge_idx))] = 1
```